# running a .sh from chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to run a .sh script from a recipe. It says Chef client completed. Running handlers complete. But the .sh script wasn't run. The recipe has the below. What is wrong?

```
execute "run script" do 
    command "sh /scratch/chef/installm.sh compact /scratch/chef" 
end
```

Comment: Hrm, chef debugging is such a pain...see what happens if you add `action :run` on the line after `command ...`.

Comment: run is already the default so that isn't it. Run your chef-client with `-l debug` to get the full debugging information. Ensure you see the recipe with this resource being evaluated and then look for `execute[run script]`. You should see the output from the command after that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run with -l debug option. The .sh script was throwing an error saying JAVA_HOME wasn't set. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the installm.sh script already there at client node where you are trying to run the cookbook? else try copying the script using source.

```
cookbook_file "/scratch/chef/installm.sh" do
  source "installm.sh"
  mode 0755
 end
```

> keep install.sh in your cookbook path cookbook_name/files/default